# printing L while showing list

Tags: pandas

Can anyone explain why the following code adds an extra L in the output?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5,7,4,5,6,4,7,8,9],
               'b':[3,5,6,2,4,6,7,8,7,8,9]})
print df['a'].values.tolist()
```

My output is:

```
[1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L]
```

Comment: For some reason you are storing the data as a `long` type.

Comment: As a complete side note, `np` is the generally accepted abbreviation for `numpy`.

Comment: This isn't printing like that for me.

Comment: Thanks, 'nm' was a typo.